# HTTP Put request flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to perform put request to update data on the database.
Ideally, each time I press button, I need  update status on database. Here is my put request:

```
Future<DataModel> submitData(String status, int testimonial_id) async {
  final response = await http.put(
      Uri.http('10.0.2.2:5001', '/update/testimony/$testimonial_id'),
      body: {
        "status": status,
      });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String responseString = response.body;
    // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return dataModelFromJson(responseString);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load info');
  }
}
```

Also see my button

```
Widget myLayoutWidget(int testimonial_id) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 4,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                showToastAccept();
                String status = 'approve';
                DataModel? data = await submitData(status, testimonial_id);
                setState(() {
                  _dataModel = data;
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Approve",
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: what's your actual query?

Comment: Thank you @JahidulIslam the problem was my String at the backend. Its now working !